# Unexpected timezone error

Tags: java, jodatime

I'm getting the following exception when trying to pass the timezone: `Etc/GMT+8` for conversion:

```
    DateTimeZone toTimeZone = DateTimeZone.forID(toTimeZoneData);
```

raises:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The datetime zone id 'Etc/GMT+8' is not recognised - null
```

This is a [valid timezone ID](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html), but still I’m getting this error. I'm not sure why.  I'm using Joda Time 2.2.

Comment: _This is a valid timezone ID_ What makes you think so?

Comment: Also, this works for me.

Comment: I got the valid JODA timezone from here : http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html

Comment: Yes, that was confusing, since this isn't working for me.

Comment: Consider upgrading versions.

Comment: Any way's in which i can debug this.I don't have much idea about JODA-TIME

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94143/discussion-between-chittprakash-and-sotirios-delimanolis).

Comment: FYI - While `"Etc/GMT+8"` is indeed a valid zone, in most cases it's better to use the locality based zones, such as `"America/Los_Angeles"`

Answer (score 2):

Time zones are stored in several [data files](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/tree/master/src/main/java/org/joda/time/tz/src) in the Joda-Time jar, and pulled from the [IANA](http://www.iana.org/time-zones), a canonical source of worldwide time zones.  See the relevant Joda-Time documentation on [updating the time zone data files](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/tz_update.html).

Like @SotiriosDelimanolis, I've verified that `DateTimeZone.forID("Etc/GMT+8");` succeeds on my machine, which is running Joda-Time 2.3.  The current release, 2.9, should work similarly.  I've also verified that the data files in [2.2](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/releases/tag/v2.2) contain the Etc zones.

If you are getting this error you are either:

1. running an old or corrupted version of Joda-Time and should upgrade.
2. building from the source with invalid data files and should refresh your data files.
3. not actually passing in the string you think you are.

Looking at the error message #3 doesn't seem like the culprit, but it's certainly possible (particularly if you didn't directly copy-paste the message).